# Deploy .msi with parameters

Tags: windows, windows-installer

I have a software sqlncli.msi that I have to install on some computer. But I have a configuration to do.
I have to intall the software by GPO. I will like deploy in silent mode but with the right configuration (for example : Name of a data source, user/password, name of server, ...)

Has you a software for realized a package msi with its configuration ? (I have try with orca.exe but I did not succeed)

Comment: What do you mean with _"...install the software **by** GPO..."_? Does your MSI need specific GPO policies? Do you  have to deploy and install some policies? Do you need to deploy your MSI **through** GPO? If it's the last one you just need to create the policy and configure it, all settings can be _calculated_ by installer itself (even if you  have very convoluted rules you can always write an extension...(

Comment: I need to deploy sqlncli.msi through GPO. But the installation must be automatic. That is to say that the parameters for the name of the server, the user/password, ... must already be informed. I have look in group policy management but I have not been able to

Comment: OK, how do you _calculate_ those parameters? Is there a set of complex rules or they're easy to infer from local information? Also: what are you using to create your MSI? WiX?

Comment: It was already a .msi when I downloaded it. Should I make the package ? The parameters are : Name of servern User/Password, ...

Comment: OK, you're not writing that MSI. Hmmm maybe SO isn't right place for this question then, anyway...the point is HOW those parameters are calculated. Is server name fixed? Is Username just the current user name? Is Password a random bunch of characters? If they're fixed then you can pass parameters to your MSI via command line (check verbose MSI install logs and MSDN to see every supported parameter). Note: with GPO you can have an install script where you can do anything you want. Last note: you can apply extra configuration (for settings you can't control directly with MSI) using a MSP...

Comment: Yes, the name of server, user, password are fixed. I will look how to do so. Thanks you for your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a transforms file (.mst) and pass it into the msi, something like

```
myinstaller.msi TRANSFORMS=mytransforms.mst
```

It's fairly trivial with something like [InstEd It](http://www.instedit.com) to open the .msi and create a transforms file.

Alternatively you can set the individual properties when you invoke the installer, [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367988(v=vs.85).aspx) demonstrates it like so:

```
msiexec /i A:\Example.msi PROPERTY=VALUE
```

Comment: I have try with ORCA.EXE (for create .mst) but I did not succeed, I will try with InstEd it. Thanks you